# Flat top sampling to a step shape signal

Tags: sampling, fourier

## Flat Top Sampling

During transmission, noise is introduced at top of the transmission pulse which can be easily removed if the pulse is in the form of flat top. Here, the top of the samples are flat i.e. they have constant amplitude. Hence, it is called as flat top sampling or practical sampling. Flat top sampling makes use of sample and hold circuit.
[image]

Theoretically, the sampled signal can be obtained by convolution of rectangular pulse $p(t)$ with ideally sampled signal say $y_\delta(t)$, i.e.

$$y(t)=p(t)\star y_\delta(t)\tag{1}$$

To get the sampled spectrum, consider Fourier transform on both sides for equation $(1)$

$$Y\left[\omega\right]=\mathcal F\left\{p(t)\star y_\delta(t)\right\}$$

By the knowledge of convolution property,

$$Y\left[\omega\right]=P(\omega)Y_\delta(\omega)$$

Here $P(\omega)=TS_a(\omega T_2)=2\sin \omega T/\omega$

## My question

If the continue signal $x(t)$ is like:
[image]
It is a step shape wave. I sampled it by flat top sampling mentioned above. The rectangular pulse width is the same as the step width of $x(t)$. It is easy to find that the sampled signal is the same as the original signal. So the Fourier transform will not change before and after sampling. However, according the above equation $Y[\omega]=P(\omega)Y_\delta(\omega)$, the Fourier transform of the sampled signal is different from the original. **What is going on?**

Comment: You just *claim* that the two functions are different, but have you actually tried to show it?

Comment: Hm, check your equations. There are two things that might be problematic: 1) Your sampled signal $y(t)$ is *not fully* given by each sample point multiplied by a convolution of $\delta(t)$ and the rectangular function. You have to take into account that an (infinite) sum of $\delta$-functions behaves as a Dirac-comb. Its FT will scale the distance of the deltas. 2) Shouldn't $Y[ω]=P(ω)Yδ(ω)$ be $Y[ω]=P(ω)Y \ast δ(ω)$?

Comment: I guess you remember the fact that $x_c(t)$ is not a bandlimited signal, which should not have been so, and hence is improperly sampled. Nevertheless your question is interesting.

Comment: I have corrected the equation 
$Y\left[\omega\right]=P(\omega)Y_\delta(\omega)$, $Y_\delta(\omega)$ is the Fourier transform of  ideally sampled signal. The derivation above comes from [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/signals_and_systems/signals_sampling_techniques.htm) . It should suitable for any signal, no matter it is bandlimited or not.

Comment: As the answer of [Matt L.](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/4298/matt-l), maybe the two functions are essentially the same. Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: Getting to the fundamentals: if two signals $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ are equal to each other for all t, then no matter how you obtained them their every property (including every transforms, differentials, integrals etc) will be the same. In fact you should use this fact itself for claiming that the corresponding Fourier representations of both signals should yield the same result...